# RequireJS, load huge libraries only for specific pages?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

so i wanna use the [neat html tables plugin for sorting and filtering](http://www.datatables.net/) only and exactly, on one page.
I use requireJS on all pages.
Well the library is like 400 kb, so how can I avoid loading it for a specific page?

I load requireJS like this

```
 <script data-main="../js/main" src="../js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

I certainly don't want is to add a new main file for each little library that I add for a single page.

Anything I am overlooking?

Comment: There's probably a better way. I haven't used require much, but you could wrap your code in an init function, and below where you include the require script call that init function.
<script data-main="../js/main" src="../js/requirejs.js"></script>
<script>initWhatever()</script>

Comment: hmm no that does not work because requirejs is getting loaded asynchronously

Comment: Well there's definitely a better way than this, but you could parse the url and check what page you're on.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just put the `<script>` tag for your library on the page you want it on?

Comment: Maybe [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy) will suit your needs. You can specify the dependency as `define(["lazy!neatHtmlTables",...], function(neatHtmlTables,...) {...}`. It will not be loaded; rather `neatHtmlTables` is a stub that can load the real AMD module on demand with `neatHtmlTables.get()`, returning a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for some condition such as the current URL and then load the plugin like this:

```
if (/*whatever condition*/) {

   require(["plugin-name"], function() {

     // Plugin is now availbale in here.

   });
}
```

This can be done anywhere in the Javascript code.